# Problem in using AXIOS and API in react native(it shows network error in Real Device(Mobile phone))

Tags: react-native, api, axios

1. I use the link ("http://localhost:5000/api/admin/login") for fetch data from API using AXIOS.
2. But it shows network error in my emulator .

3 . so I use this (http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/admin/login) and it works.

4 . but when I use the same app in my mobile phone(Huwai y9 prime) it shows network error .

5 . ie at the same time it works in emulator but not in real Device.

-------------How should I solve this problem----------

Comment: You probably want to use `localhost:5000` instead  of just localhost.

Comment: sorry it's a typing mistake

Comment: It's a network issue then, if your app is running on localhost, your real device will not be able to access it unless u are using LAN IP address.

Comment: Is you mobile phone in the same wifi network as your computer? Do you have a firewall on your computer?

Comment: no i use different wifi network in phone and laptop. yes i have fire wll in my computer

Comment: Well if the two devices are in different networks, it's obvious, that the mobile phone can't reach your computer. Add both to the same network and (if necessary) add a firewall rule to allow access on port 5000

Comment: then u  you need your laptop to be internet accessible

Comment: ok Friends Thank you for your help. let me try that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your device should be connected to same wifi network to which the server is connected

Comment: Thank you sir God bless you